# How to change the shape selection on another slide?

Tags: vba, vsto, powerpoint, office-interop, office-addins

How can I change the shape selection on another slide programmatically?

For example:

My current selection is on the shape 5 (the shape with id = 5) of the slide 3. How can I switch the selection on the shape 6 (the shape with id = 6) of the slide 2 programmatically?

Note: I am writing code in C#, VS Ultimate 2013, PowerPoint 2013

Comment: See my previous reply.  There's nearly no reason ever to select shapes in order to work on them.

Comment: It's not the easiest idea to get used to ... I know it took a while for a friend of mine to beat it through my thick skull, but it works!  ;-)

Comment: :) I have another question, concerning to PowerPoint, if you want to challenge yourself, try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27291339/how-to-show-a-waiting-dialog-in-the-meantime-still-keep-dealing-with-powerpoin

Comment: I work in VBA, .not .NET, so I suspect any suggestion I made would be irrelevant.  In VBA, I'd look into putting my processing code into a modal form and not giving the user any way to exit until the code completed.